# How to set Visibility of Stroke of a Shape in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to implement a highlight function for a well plate visualization i implemented.
The visualization looks like this:
[image: Visualization]

I already managed to get vials crossed out based on a property, but now i need to highlight a vial based on the selection of a row in a datagrid. The selected status of the row is already assigned to choosen sample. Now i only need to know how to change the visibility of the Stroke property of a ellipse.

My idea was something like this:

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        Margin="0.5"
        StrokeThickness="5">
    <Ellipse.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Ellipse.Style>
</Ellipse>
```

But herein the visibility is assigned to the complete ellipse and so the complete ellipse will be hidden.

[image]

But i cant choose the Stroke as a Style TargetType.
Any help would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Rather than setting the visibility, you could set the thickness of the stroke. 0 for not selected, and 5 for selected.

Comment: So you want to have white 5 pixels stroke visible or not depending on value of `Selected` property? Change your data trigger to alter `StrokeThickness` (set default `0` in style and change it to `5` in data trigger), as per @Loocid comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Loccid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987253/loocid) and [Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr) for the tip of changing the thickness instead of visibility. Code now looks like this and works fine:

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        Margin="0.5"
        Stroke="#002f5d">
    <Ellipse.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Ellipse.Style>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: Note that you could also, instead, set the color, i.e. to `Transparent` or not.